# Burnt marks on motherboard frame

Tags: laptop, motherboard

I accidentally spilled glass of water on my laptop. After let my laptop dried, it was worked normally 1 day. After that, I can't turn it on. No power LED, no fan running but charging LED still on. I disassembled it and found out there are several burnt marks on mother frame. It's my first time see burnt marks on this position. Did my motherboard die?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a better image, please? The focus is not on the motherboard, so it's difficult to see what you're pointing at. From the blurriness currently, it looks like either burn marks or just plain old color design on the mobo.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The immediate danger of shorting by water damage is only the first threat to your machine. After that comes the far more insidious corrosion. Take it to a repair shop, or claim for a new machine on your insurance. If you have to ask, you don't have the skillset to tackle this yourself. (& yes, that picture is useless)

Comment: Thank you guys. Your comments make me feel better. I will take my laptop to repair shop asap. Once again, thanks!